# $X$ be Banach space with a proper dense subspace $Y$. Can the identity operator on $Y$ be extended to a continuous function from $X$ into $Y$?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $X$ be any Banach space with a proper dense subspace $Y$. Can the identity operator on $Y$  be extended to a continuous function from $X$ into $Y$ ?

Comment: If it could, then given a sequence $y_1,y_2,y_3\dots$ in Y with limit $x_0\notin Y$ we would have that $\lim y_n\in Y$ and hence a contradiction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $F$ is such an extension.  Then $F(x) = x$ for $x \in Y$.  But since $Y$ is dense, that implies $F(x) = x$ for all $x \in X$. So we must have $Y = X$.